# Loads more than one CSS and JS file in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty new in WordPress.

How can I can include CSS and JS files in a page ?

This is my code:

```
function load_files() {
        
    // CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    // JS
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/youtube-player/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js', array(), '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_files');
```

Problem is this code loads only the first CSS and JS files but not the other one.

Let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first arg must be unique

```
function load_files() {
        
    // CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    // JS
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('YTPlayer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/youtube-player/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js', array(), '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_files');
```

***Enqueue a CSS stylesheet.***

**Usage**

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

**Parameters**

**$handle**

> (string) (Required) Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique.

**$src**

> (string) (Optional) Full URL of the stylesheet, or path of the
> stylesheet relative to the WordPress root directory.
>
> Default value: ''

**$deps**

> (string[]) (Optional) An array of registered stylesheet handles this
> stylesheet depends on.
>
> Default value: array()

**$ver**

> (string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying stylesheet version
> number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for
> cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number
> is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version.
> If set to null, no version is added.
>
> Default value: false

**$media**

> (string) (Optional) The media for which this stylesheet has been
> defined. Accepts media types like 'all', 'print' and 'screen', or
> media queries like '(orientation: portrait)' and '(max-width: 640px)'.
>
> Default value: 'all'

---

***Enqueue a script.***

**Usage**

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

**Parameters**

**$handle**

> (string) (Required) Name of the script. Should be unique.

**$src**

> (string) (Optional) Full URL of the script, or path of the script
> relative to the WordPress root directory.
>
> Default value: ''

**$deps**

> (string[]) (Optional) An array of registered script handles this
> script depends on.
>
> Default value: array()

**$ver**

> (string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying script version number,
> if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache
> busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is
> automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If
> set to null, no version is added.
>
> Default value: false

**$in_footer**

> (bool) (Optional) Whether to enqueue the script before  instead
> of in the . Default 'false'.
>
> Default value: false